# How to assign html to variable in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

in php twig template I could do:

```
{% set chunk %}
   <div class="foo">
     bar {{ another_var_or_helper }}
     ...
   </div>
{% endset %}

{{ chunk }}  {# displays div #}
```

in rails I can do it with render partial or <% chunk = '..' %>. But how to do "twig style"?

Comment: A partial is the standard way to do this in rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Helper function.

```
module SomeModelNameHelper
    def html_chunk
        "<div class='foo'>Bar</div>".html_safe
    end
end
```

Then in your view you can call it thusly:

```
<%= html_chunk %>
```

Comment: I wanted to do that trick because chunk would be used twice and only in one template. So that`s why i didn`t want to use a helper or a partial

Comment: You asked for how it is done in Rails.  I provided the way it is done in Rails.  I guess, based on your response, why then do you not just hardcode it?